# How to create nested array in realm without key(React Native)

Tags: reactjs, mobile, realm, native

```
{
    "a": [
        [
            {
              "_id": "57e55b64016c3551c025abc1",
              "title": "Main Campus"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5810e2e27064497f74ad4874",
              "title": "Ahm Campus"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d5d2633a1d0680620ac3cce",
              "title": "Baroda"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d5d3af3a1d0680620ac3ef8",
              "title": "India"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              "_id": "57e55b64016c3551c025abc1",
              "title": "Main Campus"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5810e2e27064497f74ad4874",
              "title": "Ahm Campus"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d5d2633a1d0680620ac3cce",
              "title": "Baroda"
            },
            {
              "_id": "5d5d3af3a1d0680620ac3ef8",
              "title": "India"
            }
          ]

    ]
  }
```

How to create the schema in the realm(React native) for this type of JSON object. I tried all possible ways but did not found any specific solution. Basically, it is a nested array where the second array does not have any specific key(I tried with key it works fine but I want to do it without adding key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
const ParentSchema = {
  name: "parent",
  properties: {
    key: "string",
    values: "Value[]"
  }
};

const ValueSchema = {
  name: "Value",
  embedded: true,
  properties: {
    _id: "string",
    title: "string"
  }
};
```

You can insert objects like:

```
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create("Parent", { key: "a", values: [
      { _id: "57e55b64016c3551c025abc1", title: "Main Campus" },
      { _id: "5810e2e27064497f74ad4874", title: "Ahm Campus" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/node/data-model

Comment: Hey @geisshirt Thanks for the answer but I dont want to add "value" is it possible to do the same without having value? I want to push JSON data the same as I have posted in question

Comment: Currently you can't but https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3392 might have your interest.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to insert direct value in Realm database without key so for now we need to modify data and then we can store in following schema.

```
const ParentSchema = {
  name: "parent",
  properties: {
   a: "level[]"
  }
};

const level = {
    name: 'level',
    properties: {
        level: 'sites[]'
    }
}
const sites = {
    name: 'sites',
    properties: {
        sites: 'site[]'
    }
}
const site = {
    name: 'site',
    properties: {

        title: 'string?',
        _id: 'string?',
        version: 'int?',
    }
}
```

Data modification need to done like following.

```
var a = {
    level: []
 }

data.a.map((Site, index) => {
         const sites = []
         Site.map((s) => { sites.push(s)})
         a.level.push({sites})
 })
```